# Google Analytics Data API Setup - service email

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

Do you have to use the service account email address that is given to you or can you use an existing email address that is connected to the accounts you have access to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

service account credentials are a specific type of credentials created on google cloud console and are used to denote your application.   Service accounts also allow for pre-authorized Access to private under data by in the case of google analytics adding the service account email address as a user in google analytics.

No you can't use a standard gmail user account as a service account.

You would need to use oauth2 to request consent of the owner or user of the google analytics account to access it.

Comment: Thank you @DaImTo. So I would need to add the service account email to every single account I want access to?

Comment: Or you could use OAuth2 and request authorization of a user who has access to all those accounts.    Service accounts are pre authorized, they dont have access to anything until you grant them that access manually though the admin section.

Comment: THANK YOU DaImTo. This will definitely save me some time. Thanks